# How to send data to Nginx server?

Tags: nginx, server, electron, sentry

I'm hoping to get some help configuring data that has to be sent from my Electron application through an Nginx web server.

Our dev team's current needs require us to log crashes and exceptions that occur in the Electron app using a service called Sentry.io BUT we must first route these crashes and exceptions through our Nginx server before making it through to the Sentry.io service.

Does anybody know an effective way to send this exception data to Nginx from Electron? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you need to change the request in transit using nginx? or simply foreward it?

Comment: The Nginx server would simply forward the request (it's an odd thing to have to do but it's required due to medical restrictions on infrastructure at the hospitals we're developing for). But first I need to get data from the Electron app to Nginx in general

Comment: You just need a simple `proxy_pass` and since it is API it wont be much problematic. See this article https://tarunlalwani.com/post/nginx-proxypass-server-paths/

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you, I do understand that I will need to use proxy_pass in my Nginx server to route the data. But do you know how to configure the Electron app to send the data in the first place?

Comment: Wouldn't `axios` work for you? You have a event for unhandled exception in electron and in that you can fire a request, not sure why it is an issue?

Comment: isn't an electron app a simple js app? can't you use regular http calls?